# BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[1:34] [bool] failed to parse field [must]') in Elastic Search (8.9.0)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-8

Following is the semantic search code using elastic search. The code is supposed to return all the records matching the given input:

```
INPUT = input("Enter the Input Query ")
token_vector = token_instance.get_token(INPUT)

query  ={
  "_source": ["title", "job_description"], 
   "size":50,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "knn":{
                  "vector":{
                     "vector":token_vector,
                     "k":20
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}


res = es.search(index='posting1',
                body=query,
                request_timeout=55)

title = [x['_source']  for x in res['hits']['hits']] 
title
```

Error: BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[1:34] [bool] failed to parse field [must]')

How to fix this error? **I'm using Elasticsearch 8.9.0**. I tried the existing solutions to this  error, but they don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `body` parameter in the [`search()` function](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.9.0/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search), you need to call it like this:

```
query  ={
   "bool":{
      "must":[
         {
            "knn":{
               "vector":{
                  "vector":token_vector,
                  "k":20
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
res = es.search(index='posting1',
                size=50,
                source=["title", "job_description"],
                query=query,
                request_timeout=55)
```